# How to resolve y_true_val = list(y_true.values()) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'?

Tags: python, list, data-mining, social-networking, listobject

I am trying to write code for the Zachary karate club dataset. Now I am stuck at the line

```
y_true_val = list(y_true.values())
```

My code:

```
nmi_results = []
ars_results = []

y_true_val = list(y_true.values())

# Append the results into lists
for y_pred in results:

    nmi_results.append(normalized_mutual_info_score(y_true_val, y_pred))
    ars_results.append(adjusted_rand_score(y_true_val, y_pred))

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True, figsize=(16, 5))

x = np.arange(len(y_pred))
avg = [sum(x) / 2 for x in zip(nmi_results, ars_results)]

xlabels = list(algorithms.keys())

sns.barplot(x, nmi_results, palette='Blues', ax=ax1)
sns.barplot(x, ars_results, palette='Reds', ax=ax2)
sns.barplot(x, avg, palette='Greens', ax=ax3)

ax1.set_ylabel('NMI Score')
ax2.set_ylabel('ARS Score')
ax3.set_ylabel('Average Score')

# # Add the xlabels to the chart
ax1.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
ax2.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
ax3.set_xticklabels(xlabels)

# Add the actual value on top of each bar
for i, v in enumerate(zip(nmi_results, ars_results, avg)):
    ax1.text(i - 0.1, v[0] + 0.01, str(round(v[0], 2)))
    ax2.text(i - 0.1, v[1] + 0.01, str(round(v[1], 2)))
    ax3.text(i - 0.1, v[2] + 0.01, str(round(v[2], 2)))

# Show the final plot
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
y_true_val = list(y_true.values())

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: It appears your `y_true` is already a list.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Specifically: (1) Your posted code fails at the third active line, as `y_true` is undefined; (2) You haven't provided the expected values trace: what is `y_true` at the point of failure, and where did its value deviate from your expectations?

Comment: So what should I have to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!

**First let's learn about the error:**

- As mentioned in the comments `attribute` error happens when you try to access a method that is not defined in that object's call methods.
- For example, in py string objects we have `.lower()` available to generate a new string in lowercase(From `ABC` to `abc`). If you try to access this `.lower()` for an integer object you will receive Attribute error.

**How to fix this error?**

1. Use python inbuilt **type** operator to determine what kind of datatype/object you have. If it's a list then you don't have to do any `.values()`

   ```
   print(type(y_true))
   ```
2. Use python inbuilt **dir** operator to know which are operators available for this object. If you see the `values` operator here, only then apply `.values()` operation.

   ```
   print(dir(y_true))
   ```
3. Still not sure, or ran into some other error try to `print(y_true)` to see what you have.